# Why doesn't Perl's encoding layer have any effect?

Tags: perl, character-encoding

I need to read a file encoded in iso-8859-1.

For some reason I can't get the encoding layer (as described in `PerlIO::encoding`) to work. Here's a minimal example of what I am doing.

`test.txt` contains a single pound sign encoded in iso-8859-1.

```
% iconv -f iso-8859-1 test.txt
£

% hexdump -C test.txt
00000000  a3 0a                                             |..|
00000002
```

My Perl script:

```
#!/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

open my $f, "<:encoding(iso-8859-1)", $ARGV[0] or die qq{Could not open $ARGV[0]: $!};

while (<$f>) {
  print;
}
```

Result:

```
% ./script.pl test.txt | hexdump -C
00000000  a3 0a                                             |..|
00000002
```

So the script prints the exact byte sequence it reads, with no
conversion performed.

Comment: I'd suggest debugging issues like these with [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) with its `Useqq` option turned on, [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump), or even [`Devel::Peek`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Devel/Peek.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A string is a sequence of (32-bit or 64-bit) numbers.

In a string containing decoded text, those numbers are Unicode Code Points. Since byte `A3` represents Unicode Code Point `U+00A3` under iso-8859-1, `decode("iso-8859-1", "\xA3")` therefore returns `"\xA3"`.

You proceeded to print that string, and `print("\xA3")` on a file handle with no encoding layers produces the byte `A3` (since it expects a strings of bytes).

---

You didn't specify what you wanted to do, but I'm guessing you wanted the program to produce convert the input from iso-8859-1 to UTF-8. To achieve that,

Add

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(locale)';
```

or

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

These add an encoding layer to STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR (using `binmode`), and they set the default encoding layer for `open` in scope.

Comment: This doesn't seem accurate. What does it even mean to print a non-encoded Unicode code point? It seems to me that Perl is using its [internal encoding](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunifaq.html#I-lost-track%3B-what-encoding-is-the-internal-format-really%3F), which happens also to be Latin1 in this case.

Comment: A string is a just a sequence of number. In a string containing decoded text, those number are Unicode Code points. `decode("iso-8859-1", "\xA3")` therefore returns `"\xA3"`. `print("\xA3")` on a file handle with no encoding layers produces the byte `A3`.

Comment: The internal representation is irrelevant. In fact, the internal representation of `decode("iso-8859-1", "\xA3")` isn't `A3,UTF8=0`; it's `C2.A3,UTF8=1`

Comment: If your theory was correct, `perl -le 'use Encode; print(decode("utf-8", "ы"));'` would result in something like `04 4b` (0x044b is the unicode code point for ы); but instead it gives `d1 8b`, the utf-8 encoding of 'ы'.

Comment: My answer simply doesn't cover what happens when you provide an invalid input. When faced with an invalid input (`0x44b > 0xFF`), `print` warns ("wide character"), and guesses that you meant to encode using utf8.

Answer (score 5):

I was assuming that file handles not declared with a specific encoding use the utf-8 encoding by default, but apparently that isn't true.

Adding an explicit

```
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
```

fixes the problem.

Comment: See also the [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html) pragma, e.g. `use open qw/:std :utf8/;` (although note that its effect is broader)

Comment: That is definitely not true. Perl was (and still is) used to process raw binary data long before it was used to handle character set encoding. The default layer is `:raw` (`:crlf` for text-mode files on Windows) and changing that would be backwards-incompatible.

Comment: Or `use open OUT => ':utf8';` see [open pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/open.html)